# como guardar cambio de una columna en el mismo dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy trabajando en python con un dataframe, y estoy removiendo un elemento especifico de la columna si se cumple la condicion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi estoy removiendo los ceros:

```
list_temp=[]
for i in data['columna']:
    if i[4]!='0':
       list_temp=i
    elif i[4]=='0': #si en el indice 4 hay un cero remplazarlo.
       list_temp=i.replace('0','',1)

print(list_temp)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el output que me da.

lo que no logro es guarda eso eso en el datadrame, en la misma columna que estoy usando.

si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradeceria mucho.

gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primero, para obtener una lista con todos los valores ya modificados, no debes hacer `list_temp=i` y `list_temp=i.replace('0','',1)`, porque entonces reasignas a la variable `list_temp` la cadena, en vez de agregarla a la lista. Debes hacer `list_temp.append(i)` y `list_temp.append(i.replace('0', '', 1))`.

Dicho esto, puedes simplemente usar la lista para reasignar los nuevos valores a la columna existente:

```
data["columna"] = list_temp
```

ahora bien, una observación, `str.replace` elimina el primer carácter que encuentra en la cadena, lo que significa que te eliminara el cero equivocado en casos como `"906-0142"` (quedando como `"96-0142"` en vez de `"906-142"`), lo cual puede ser un problema si se puede dar el caso en tus datos reales. Por ejemplo, una forma mas robusta de eliminar el cero en el indice 4 si existe es simplemente reconstruir la cadena descartando ese indice mediante dos rebanados:

```
cadena[:4] + cadena[5:]
```

que aplicado a tu caso podría ser:

```
data["columna"] = [
    cad[:4] + cad[5:] if len(cad) > 4 and cad[4] == "0" else cad
    for cad in data["columna"]
    ]
```

Otra forma es usar directamente `pandas.Series.str.replace` y una expresión regular:

```
data["columna"] = data["columna"].str.replace(r"^(.{4})0(.*)", r"\1\2", regex=True)
```

Donde:

- `^` -> Fija la posición al principio de una línea
- `(.{4})` -> Primer grupo de captura. Cualquier carácter, 4 veces
- `0` -> Carácter "0"
- `(.*)` -> Segundo grupo de captura. Cualquier carácter, cero o mas veces.

Si la expresión coincide, se reemplaza la cadena por el contenido del primer grupo de captura concatenado con el contenido del segundo grupo (`\1\2`), es decir, toda la cadena menos el cero del indice 4.

O si como parece, lo que deseas es eliminar todo cero a la izquierda del segundo numero, el que va después del guion, puedes también hacer:

```
data["columna"] = data["columna"].str.replace(r"^([0-9]*-)0+([0-9]*)", r"\1\2", regex=True)
```

---

Si en vez de solo querer eliminar los ceros a la izquierda del segundo numero, se quisiera eliminar todos los ceros a la izquierda de cada numero existente separado por un guion, se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
data["columna"] = [
    "-".join(sub_cad.lstrip("0")
             for sub_cad in cad.split("-"))
    for cad in data["columna"]
    ]
```

o también:

```
data["columna"] = data["columna"].str.split("-").apply(
                    lambda row: "-".join(num.lstrip("0") for num in row)
                    )
```

ambas, convierten *"09510-005070-0235"* en *"9510-5070-235"*.